# How to make array have same number of samples?

Tags: python, keras

I am a beginner using CNN and Keras and I am trying to make a program to predict whether someone could develop diabetes using data in a CSV file. I think I am getting confused with how to reshape the array as I am receiving the error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 8
  y sizes: 768
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten

# read in the csv file using pandas
data = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv")

# extract the input and output columns from the dataframe
X = data.drop(columns=['Outcome'])
y = data['Outcome']

# reshape the input data into the shape expected by a CNN
X = X.values.reshape(8, 768, 1)

# create a Sequential model in Keras
model = Sequential()

# add a 2D convolutional layer with 32 filters and a kernel size of 3x3
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(8, 768, 1)))

# add a flatten layer to flatten the output from the convolutional layer
model.add(Flatten())

# add a fully-connected layer with 64 units and a ReLU activation
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))

# add a fully-connected layer with 10 units and a softmax activation
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

# compile the model using categorical crossentropy loss and an Adam optimizer
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

# fit the model using the input and output data
model.fit(X, y)

# print prediction
print(model.predict(10, 139, 80, 0, 0, 27.1, 1.441, 57))
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error.

Comment: `model.predict(10, 139, 80, 0, 0, 27.1, 1.441, 57)` is definitely a part of the code that needs to be fixed, but the described error seems to have to do with `fit`. I'd suggest that you provide more details on the error you get, as well as on your input data and why its shape is `(8, 768, 1)`. Are there 24x32 images?

Answer (score 0):

Tldr, you probably don't want a CNN in this case.
First off, I’m assuming your data looks something like the following, if that’s not the case the rest of the post may be way off target:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/335HJ.png)

So there are 768 rows or patients, 8 inputs for each row, and  1 output (known as the label).
Convolutional layers are used when there is an input signal that you wish to analyze. In 2d, this would be something like a grid of pixels, or in 1d it might be time series data. Your data is neither – each row of the data represents a single 8-dimensional data point (i.e. a single patient) at a single point in time, so you very likely don’t want to use a convolutional layer at all.

For more information, you can read up on the differences between convnets and fully connected neural networks here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5546/what-is-the-difference-between-a-convolutional-neural-network-and-a-regular-neur?rq=1
“CNN, in specific, has one or more layers of convolution units. A convolution unit receives its input from multiple units from the previous layer which together create a proximity. Therefore, the input units (that form a small neighborhood) share their weights.

The convolution units (as well as pooling units) are especially beneficial as:
•   They reduce the number of units in the network (since they are many-to-one mappings). This means, there are fewer parameters to learn which reduces the chance of overfitting as the model would be less complex than a fully connected network.
•   They consider the context/shared information in the small neighborhoods. This feature is very important in many applications such as image, video, text, and speech processing/mining as the neighboring inputs (eg pixels, frames, words, etc) usually carry related information."

A very naïve, very basic NN for a problem like this would just use Dense, i.e. fully connected layers.
In Keras, you can do the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu", input_shape=(8,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Note that the last layer is a single neuron, since you have only one output. If you were classifying images as one of say 10 categories (dog, cat, bird, etc), then you would use 10 output nodes in the last layer, softmax them, and use categorical cross entropy. Here, with a single condition, you only need a single output node and note that the loss function should probably be binary crossentropy – i.e. you’re trying to detect the presence or absence of the condition.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think so. He's reading in diabetes.csv into a pandas dataframe.